# What's the meaning of "dry" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Consider this comment:

> Quality of service at restaurants is dropping, and I don't think it's the servers' fault, I think it's the fault of management for cutting back on staff.
>
> Several times now out with friends after work my **beer's gone dry**, and rather than cutting the server's tip, I go to the manager afterwards and pressure to get compensation for the terrible service.  Since they can't give away alcohol, they give gift cards good for food only; fair enough.

What does it mean when the poster describes his beer has gone *dry*?

Comment: It means the cup/mug has gone dry. It's empty. Typically servers will offer another round or refill before that happens.

Comment: lol ok. I never drank beer before so I had no clue. So I'm guessing the poster here is saying that the server handed him an empty mug of beer and not realize it?

Comment: or he waited long enough for the beer to get dry and complain about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the States it's common that waiters (servers) in diners will top up your coffee regardless whether you ask for an extra cup or not (Americans drink gazillions of that black liquid stuff), but I'm unaware if this is also true with alcohol.

However, the author, implies that this is indeed the case, so when his glass of beer has been drunk *dry* (the glass is empty) he expects the *server* in the restaurant to refill his glass without being prompted.

Comment: It's not true for alcohol. But servers are supposed to notice that your glass is empty and ask whether you want another beer relatively quickly.

Comment: @PeterShor Thank you. I was unsure as I've only been to the states once. A truly wonderful experience, just wish I had the money to afford another trip.